# How to convert ComboBox.SelectedItem to string

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox

When saving to a database, the field referring to the text of a ComboBox is saved as `Windows.UI.Xaml.ComboBoxItem`.

What is the correct way to convert and save the text referring to the selected item in the ComboBox?

ComboBox in XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox
    x:Name="TipoComboBox"
    Width="300"
    Margin="{StaticResource SmallTopMargin}"
    Header="Bill Type"
    PlaceholderText="Select if it's payable or receivable bill"
    RelativePanel.Below="DescricaoTextBox">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="APagarComboBox" Content="Bill Payable" />
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="AReceberComboBox" Content="Bill Receivable" />
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```cs
var conta = new Conta
{
    Vencimento = Convert.ToString(this.VencimentoDatePicker.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")),
    Descricao = this.DescricaoTextBox.Text,
    Tipo = this.TipoComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), // Windows.UI.Xaml.ComboBoxItem
    Categoria = this.CategoriaTextBox.Text,
    Valor = this.ValorTextBox.Text,
};
```

Please advise how to fix this.

**EDIT**

I've matched @Joelius' comments with @MK.DEVELOPER's answer, and obtained this line of code to solve my problem:

```
Tipo = (this.TipoComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()
```

Comment: Just calling `ToString` on a `Windows.UI.Xaml.ComboBoxItem` will not display the content. You have to convert the [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ContentControl_Content) to a string using `TipoComboBox.SelectedItem.Content.ToString()`. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837749/10883465) shows how you can do that.

Comment: @Joelius thanks for comment, but adding `Content` raises a [CS1061](https://www.bing.com/search?q=CS1061++C%23+%27object%27+does+not+contain+a+definition+for+%27Content%27+and+no+accessible+extension+method+%27Content%27+accepting+a+first+argument+of+type+%27object%27+could+be+found+(are+you+missing+a+using+directive+or+an+assembly+reference%3f)&form=VSHELP) error.

Comment: That's to be expected, the [`SelectedItem`-Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedItem) is of type `object`. You have to do a cast first as demonstrated by the answer below (there are other ways but that should work).

Comment: @Joelius `Tipo = (this.TipoComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()` worked as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir you want to convert combobox.selecteditem to comboboxitem
example :

```
public string GetSelectedComboboxText()
{
  // replace comboboxname to combobox control name
  var item = comboboxname.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem;
      return item.Content.ToString();
}
```

any quastion i am here

Comment: When using `Tipo = (this.TipoComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()` I had the expected result. I'll accept your answer, but I'll edit the question to assert this code. Thanks.